# Smart View SDK volume control API point?

Tags: ios, swift, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to write a super simple Swift (3 or 4 version) app with at least one button: "increase Volume" for a Smart View TV(Samsung). I have added Smart View SDK to my Swift project. Do I need to develop an app for the TV or there is a simple way?

Could someone give a hint? Your support is highly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: have you found any code to do that?